# Shoulda/RSpec matchers - conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

In my code I had the following validation with Shoulda matchers, which works fine:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
```

In my model, I've added the condition to my validation:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :if => eligible?
```

Is it possible to reflect it in the validations?

I've tried looking at [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) for shoulda matchers, but haven't been able to locate the solution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 154, accepted):

It doesn't appear that shoulda_matchers does this, but it's easy enough to write it yourself::

```
  context "if eligible" do
    before { allow(subject).to receive(:eligible?).and_return(true) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  end

  context "if ineligible" do
    before { allow(subject).to receive(:eligible?).and_return(false) }
    it { should_not validate_presence_of(:name) }
  end
```

Comment: With RSpec 3: `before { allow(subject).to receive(: eligible?).and_return(true) }`

Comment: Is this the best way to go? When we stub a method, we are bypassing the real logic, which can lead to tests that pass even though the code doesn't work as expected in a real scenario...

Comment: @josegp I would argue that we are not "bypassing the real logic". The logic in the model is simple: if the return value of `eligible?` is true, perform the validation, if not, don't. That logic is exercised by this test. What *isn't* exercised is the behavior of the `eligible?` method, which presumably would be covered in different test.